# Immediate loading of UserDefaults (App Storage)

Tags: ios, swiftui, userdefaults, appstorage

I save Integer via UserDefaults (App Storage) in SwiftUI, but now the problem is that in a different structure the integers are only loaded after restarting the app, but the integers should be loaded immediately when you click the navigation link on the View is coming. The integer (in the form of a text via an if query) is loaded immediately in the same structure.

if someone can help me, I'm happy.

Thank you in advance :)

Demo Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Monday1BCalendarView: View {
    
    
    @AppStorage("Monday1B") var Monday1B: Int = 1
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
            
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Main")){
                    
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.Montag1B = 0;
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Maths")
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    })
```

And Loading:

```
import SwiftUI


struct CalendarMainView: View {
    
    var Monday1B: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Monday1B")
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            VStack{
                ZStack{
                    
                    Image("Stundenplan")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 360, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                        .position(x: 200, y: 100)
                    
                  
                    if Montag1B == 0 {
                        
                        Text("Mathe")
                    
                    }
```

Comment: Would you add demo code for an issue?

Comment: You need to use the '@AppStorage....' wrapper for the variable both times.

Comment: Ok, how should I use this?

Answer (score 1):

This line will only read from `UserDefaults` when initialised:

```
struct CalendarMainView: View {
    var Monday1B: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Monday1B")
```

If you want to *observe* changes to this value, you need `@AppStorage`:

```
struct CalendarMainView: View {
    @AppStorage("Monday1B") var Monday1B: Int = 1
    ...
```

If you end up having multiple `@AppStorage` wrappers you can create one in the parent view and pass it down to subviews.

Comment: Thanks, I’m a Swift beginner sorry for my bad question. Also I’m from Germany sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @LeoSaischowa If my answer solved your problem please accept it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `@AppStorage` in both (all) places

```
struct CalendarMainView: View {
    
    // this automatically updated
    @AppStorage("Montag1B") var Montag1B: Int = 0    

    // this read only once - on initialization
    //var Montag1B = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Montag1B")
```